# Ninject with WCF and Interception (for AOP)

Tags: wcf, attributes, ninject, aop, ninject-extensions

I've been trying to get the ninject working in wcf, using the wcf extension and the interception with dynamicproxy2 extension. I've basically created a Time attribute and have it all working in a basic scenario. Where I get trouble is when in ninject module I create my service binding with a constructor argument:

```
Bind<IMyDependency>().To<MyDependency>();
Bind<IService1>().To<Service1>().WithConstructorArgument("dependency", Kernel.Get<IMyDependency>());
```

Everything works fine, but the Time attribute wont fire on anything in my Service1 or MyDependency.

The time attribute is the standard one floating all over the internet. The only other piece of code really is the CreateKernel method is the global.asax, which looks like this:

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel() {
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(
        new NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false }, 
        new WcfNinjectModule(), 
        new DynamicProxy2Module()
    );
    return kernel;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Matt

EDIT 12/12/2011: As requested, I've added some more detail below:
The entire wcf ninject module:

```
public class WcfNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{

    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IMyDependency>().To<MyDependency>();
        Bind<IService1>().To<Service1>();
    }
}
```

The create kernel method in the global.asax is above, and the global.asax inherits from NinjectWcfApplication.

Service method looks like this:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private IMyDependency _dependency;

    public Service1()
    {
    }
    public Service1(IMyDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    [Time]
    public virtual string GetData(string value)
    {
        return string.Format(_dependency.GetMyString(), value);
    }
}
public interface IMyDependency
{
    string GetMyString();
}

public class MyDependency : IMyDependency
{
    [Time]
    public virtual string GetMyString()
    {
        return "Hello {0}";
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Since removing the 'WithConstructor' argument, the time intercept attribute will fire on GetMyString but not on GetData.

Matt

Comment: Whats the reason for using `.WithConstructorArgument("dependency", Kernel.Get<IMyDependency>());`?. Ninject will find the dependency without that itsself. 

If this does not help can you please add the full problem and not just parts of it.

Comment: I just prefer to be explicit wherever possible - but even if I remove it I get the same problem. I'll try to add some more detail above, but its difficult to add everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more work (and writing that last post edit), it turns out that just removing the WithConstructorArgument method did resolve my problem and everything now seems to be working fine.

Matt